# How can I export a 3d xarray as a parquet file in python

Tags: python, export, parquet, python-xarray

I have multiple 3D xarrays (and previous numpy arrays) and I was looking to export them as a parquet file to be able to quickly import them at a later date. Is it even possible to do this as by the looks of it parquet files prefer 2D inputs? If not, what would be the best way to export a 3D array (the data is geospatial so the third dimension is > 200).

As the data is 3D the parquet file exporter I was using was returning an error as it was expecting a pandas dataframe which again caused issues due to the 3D nature of the data.

Comment: Hey, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you add a small reproducible example of what you are trying to do? In particular an example of the 3d arrays would be helpful.

Comment: It would also help if you explained why you want to export your 3D arrays to Parquet. In general, you're going to have to collapse one of your dimensions to make this work. Is that what you want?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.